# determine if $f_n(x) = \sin(\frac x n)$ at $\mathbb{R}$ converges pointwise and uniformly

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I'm required to determine if $f_n(x) = \sin(\frac x n)$ at $ \mathbb{R}$
Converges Pointwise and uniformly.

Now, because my range is $ \mathbb{R}$ I'm leaning towards diverges, but im not quite sure how to go about proving any of the ways.

I know that since my function is Sin, its supremum would be 1, but im not sure how to use that information.

I would appreciate any advice on how to move forward with the proof.

Comment: Hint: $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {\sin \left( {\frac{x}{n}} \right)} \right| \ge \sin 1 > 0.
$$

Comment: @Gary Thanks! but wouldn't the supremum always be 1?

Comment: Yes, but it is enough to show that it is bounded from below by a positive constant. It is not always possible to compute the supremum (in similar problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it converges uniformly and pointwise then the two limits will agree. For any $x$, $x/n \to 0$ and so since $\sin$ is continuous it will converge pointwise to $0$. For uniform convergence you would need that the supremum of $|\sin(x/n)|$ tends to 0, but this is always 1 for any value of $n$.

Comment: Thanks! I was pondering on Gary's Hint but now it all comes together. what was really throwing me off was that I was thinking about how x can reach infinity because of its range, but I forgot that we check for every specific x, so even if x is close to infinity, its not infinity once we take a specific one!  much appreciated!